# Package migration from version 8 to version 3 failed with error 0xC001700A when scheduled with SQL Agent

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS. Our SQL Server version is 2008 R2 (SP3). I am trying to create an SSIS package in VS2019. Package runs and does what it's supposed to on my computer. But when I schedule it with SQL Agent, it throws this error:

`Package migration from version 8 to version 3 failed with error 0xC001700A`

Any way I can save the package as version 3 in VS2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect documentation no longer exists or is at least easily searchable for me to verify my answer but no, not really.

Before SQL Server 2016/Visual Studio 2016, a developer needed an installation of BIDS/SSDT tied to the specific version of SQL Server they were building packages for. As a consultant, that means I conceivably had SQL Server 2005/2008/2012/2014 tooling on my laptop as I didn't know what client I may run into.

Complicating matters for you is that SQL Server 2005/2008/2008R2 only shipped the editor environment, Business Intelligence Design(er?) Studio, on the same physical media as SQL Server as that is how the tool was licensed. You need to have someone at work scrounge up a SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition .iso file so you can install BIDS.

Oh and then you have to rewrite the package as there's no

### Extremely short sighted approach

If it's a one and done type of thing and you can't find the installation media, [Biml Studio](https://www.varigence.com/BimlStudio/) can probably serve as a bridge.

1. Install Biml Studio with the trial/temporary license
2. Create a new Biml Project
3. Reverse Engineer/Import the package created in VS 2019 into the project
4. Change the target property to SQL Server 2008 R2
5. Build/Emit the package and now you have a valid 2008 R2 package (assuming you didn't use something in the 2019 version that didn't exist a decade ago)

What this does is convert an SSIS package into a domain specific language that describes the ETL and then compiles those instruction back into an older dialect of SSIS. Not sure if that'd be classified as transpiling but that's what I propose you do

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I downloaded sql server 2008 r2 and re did the package, it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If that resolved the issue, you're welcome to click the checkmark next to this (or any answer) to mark the question as closed